# Prove $\text{rad}(I)/I$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{N}(R/I)$

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, abstract-algebra

I want to know if this is the correct way to do it. 
Define $\varphi:\text{rad}(I) \longrightarrow \mathfrak{N}(R/I)$ by $\varphi(r)= r^n+I$,then ker$\varphi = I$, so therefore by the 1st isomorphism theorem, we have:

$$\text{rad}(I)/I \cong \mathfrak{N}(R/I) $$

it satisfies the condition for homomorphism, since

$$\varphi(r_1r_2) = (r_1r_2)^n+I = \varphi(r_1)\varphi(r_2),$$ 
$$\varphi(r_1+r_2)= (r_1^n+r_2^n) + I = \varphi(r_1)+\varphi(r_2). $$

Do I need to prove something else, or do I miss something? Any help would be appreciate it , thanks

Comment: why $\phi$ is well defined?? why it is surjective??

Comment: so if i prove that $\varphi$ is surjective and welldefined, im done?

Comment: One thing you should find suspicious is your choice of n in your map. What n? Why that particular n? That should suggest to you that it isn't really a good idea.

Comment: @rschwieb I get it now why is not working,however i was thinking that for every $r_i \in radI$ there exist $n_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $r_i^{n_i} \in I$, so if i define $m = $ max ${n_i}$ for all $i$, then: $\varphi(r)= r^m+I$, will contain all power of $r_i$, so in this case it is not a particular $n$,since we can write $r_i^{m} = r_i^{n_i}(r_i^{m-n_i})$ not sure if this would work, probably would do the proof showing equality.

Comment: @RicardoCervantes you've got no guarantee the max exists. Anyhow, the two sets are equal pretty much by definition (depending on your definitions.) you probably shouldn't spend time looking for a map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x \in rad(I) \Leftrightarrow x^n \in I,$ for some $n \geq 1.$ So,
$x + I \in rad(I)/I \Leftrightarrow x^n + I = 0$ in $R/I$ for some $n \geq 1 \Leftrightarrow (x + I )^n = 0$ in $R/I$ for some $n \geq 1 \Leftrightarrow x + I \in \mathfrak{N}(R/I).$

Comment: so this prove the $\varphi$ is welldefined and surjective?

Comment: @Ricardo Cervantes: no. I'm not using any isomorphism, just the definitions of radical ideal and nilradical.

Comment: i will talk to my professor because the book says that we must prove that they are equal, and the professor ask to prove that they are isomorphic, so my question is if they are equal then they are isomorphic?

Comment: Equal is probably what was meant (although being equal implies they are isomorphic as well.)